# Filtro em um projeto que consiste em vários projetos e que são executados em diferentes portas (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microsserviços

Gostaria de saber se há como (e como posso) desenvolver uma aplicação que é constituída de várias outras aplicações e, para acessar essas outras partes da aplicação eu preciso ter feito o login.

Acredito que esse conceito está ligado aos microserviços ou estou enganado? É possível desenvolver esse interceptador que irá fazer a verificação dos logins nos projetos que rodam nessas portas?

Comment: Sim tem como fazer, a forma mais primitiva é com um HttpClint, mas existem implementações que abstraem-se um pouco isso.

Comment: Pode comentar um pouco mais? ou mandar algum link de referência?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Só para conceituar as coisas, o que você está descrevendo chama-se microservices, vários serviços pequenos cooperando, com single-sign-on (ou SSO) - um login vale para todas as aplicações. Infelizmente não tenho tempo para elaborar uma resposta completa sobre o assunto, mas um começo seria você ter uma aplicação responsável pelo login que gera um token para o cliente que é então validado quando a requisição vai para outros serviços.

Answer (score 2):

Dividir uma aplicação em outras menores faz parte do conceito de microserviços, mas não é tudo. Existem várias definições, mas uma importante é que cada microserviço deve refletir um aspecto relevante do sistema.

A comunicação entre os serviços geralmente é feita usando HTTP e algum protocolo de mais alto nível. Pode ser um *ad hoc* com REST e JSON mesmo ou algo mais elaborado como o Google Protobuf.

Quando à autenticação, você pode deve estudar oAuth e procurar alguma implementação de Single Sign-On (SSO). Há várias formas de implementar isto e existem alguns frameworks prontos (me lembro do [Josso](http://www.josso.org/), mas faz tempo, deve ter coisa melhor hoje).

O funcionamento básico é mais ou menos assim:

- Os usuários se autenticam no servidor de SSO e retorna um token para o cliente/usuário/browser.
- A cada requisição para outro serviço, o cliente inclui o token.
- Os outros serviços validam com o servidor de SSO se o token é realmente válido.

Mas, lembrando, tudo isso pode ser abstraído. Existem inclusive alguns serviços disponíveis na internet que podem ser usados caso você queira mais produtividade para se focar no negócio e não perder tempo criando sua própria solução, tal como o [Auth0](https://auth0.com/).

Uma técnica comum em microserviços é criar um serviço "façade" contendo toda a API externa da sua aplicação. Ela pode ser responsável por autenticar e autorizar cada requisição. Assim você não precisa expor cada serviço na internet em portas diferentes e a implementação dos microserviços fica transparente para os clientes.